# How to solve this not properly scaled background for custom shaped button?

Tags: android, xml

This what i got:

[image]

I want to get nice resizeable triangle custom shaped button, that have triangle as shape but with resizing, it proportionally resize, now i got just button triangle  in left bottom side.

This is code for custom shaped xml for backround button:
https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/

**EDIT2** : Source code for custom shape button.xml from above link:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="87%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="@color/transparent" android:width="10dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/your_color_here" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**EDIT** : `"@drawable/background_buttons"` == custom shaped xml

This is code for this two button in layout:

```
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/Button02"
       android:background="@drawable/background_buttons"
       android:layout_width="220dp"
       android:layout_height="120dp"
      />

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="220dp"
       android:layout_height="120dp"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: What does your original image look like?

Comment: Sorry i didn't write background_buttons == custom shaped xml

Comment: What does "background_buttons == custom shaped xml" mean?

Comment: You asked for background of button, what image looks like?  I set shape of button in backround_buttons.xml

Comment: It will help if you post the source of `background_buttons.xml`.